# @LastModifiedDate doesn't work when only nested nested object is updated

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a **Unit** entity and I'm using the @LastModifiedDate annotation to keep track of the updates. The problem is that in case I only update the `items` field the `updateDate` field isn't updated with the new date but if I update any other fields in the **Unit** entity the `updateDate` field is updated properly.

```
//other annotations
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Unit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    private String unitId;
    private String unitName;

    //other fields

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @OrderBy("slotNumber")
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

Unit repository

```
public interface UnitRepo extends CrudRepository<Unit, String> {
    Set<Unit> findAllByProfileUsername(String username);
}
```

And my update method in my Unit service

```
public Unit updateUnit(Unit unit) {
        return repo.save(unit);
    }
```

Comment: You're modifying an Item, not the Unit. The @LastModifiedDate field only updates for changes in the entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@LastModifiedDate` will only update the modified date when the changes have been made in the entity parameters, not the relationship. When you only modify the Item, *updateDate* will not be updated. You may find the [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2351)<sub>(for mongo)</sub> related to the same.

In case you want to modify the updateDate, you may implement the entity listeners with the `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` (see [JPA Lifecycle](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events)). You may also have a look into [AuditorAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/#auditing.auditor-aware)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback methods in your Unit Entity class.which allows to detect the changes before / after to the entity class. `@PreUodate` and `@PostUpdate` you can try.

References -
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html