# Spring Auditing: Getting latest last_modified_date from all related entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, audit

I'm using Spring AuditingEntityListener to collect audit information on my entities.

I'm looking for a way to collect the last change-date (and user) of a set of related entities.

For example, when having three entities like this:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class EntityA {

    private long id;
    
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityAId")
    private List<EntityB> bS;
}

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class EntityB {

    private long id;

    private long entityAId;
    
    @LastModifiedDate private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityBId")
    private List<EntityC> cS;
}

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class EntityC {

    private long id;

    private long entityBId;
    
    @LastModifiedDate private Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

What's the best way to get the latest lastModifiedDate from all three Entities?

Comment: take a look here, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67475112/lastmodifieddate-doesnt-work-when-only-nested-nested-object-is-updated